# Not allowed in prolog grails XML error

Tags: xml, grails

I have the following on a Curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d '<sample:WIB xmlns:sample="www.sample.com"><sample:Customer><sample:Catalog_ID>01</sample:Catalog_ID><sample:Shop_ID>01</sample:Shop_ID></sample:Customer></sample:WIB>' http://localhost:8080/app/API/
```

My Grails controller is:

```
def index() {
    String xml = request.XML.toString();
    def workXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
}
```

I get the error when parsing
I have also tried this:

```
def workXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).declareNamespace(sample: 'sample')
```

I get the same error:

This is the stack trace:

```
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Line | Method
->>   10 | index     in app.APIController$$EP3387M0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: check the actual XML.  it either is no XML at all (e.g. server error page) or it is just not valid at all.

Comment: I have provided the XML and it is valid. Refer to the Curl command

Comment: i mean the actual XML you are trying to parse.  the XML you type works, but who knows whats in your `String xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong option to `curl` - the `-d` option expects `name=value` pairs and treats them like a form post from a browser. If you want to send exactly the data given on the command line as-is you should use `--data-binary` instead.

As an aside, `request.XML` is already parsed - it's a `GPathResult` the same as you would get from `XmlSlurper` so there's no need to try converting it back to a string and slurping it again.